# Let X be a space of Peano and $x \in X$ a point that is not cutting.

Tags: general-topology

Then $\forall V$ neighborhood of $x$, there exists an open and connected neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U \subseteq V$ and $X - U$ and connected.

This is true? If so, what would be the most appropriate proof?
I try, but I could not solve.

Comment: Do you mean X - U is connected? That's easily not always possible, e.g. in [0,1].

Comment: You should give the definition of a Peano space.